# Load an object with values with reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

With the code below I am trying to save and load a player class into and from an xml document. I have the write portion working but I am having some trouble with repopulating the player object with the data stored in the playerElement. I would prefer not to use the xml serializer classes.

```
    public class Player
    {
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public int HitPoint { get; set; }
       public int ManaPoint { get; set; }
    }


    public Player LoadPlayer(XElement playerElement)
    {

        Player player = new Player();

        PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(Player).GetProperties();

        foreach (XAttribute attribute in playerElement.Attributes())
        {
            PropertyInfo property = typeof(Player).GetProperty(attribute.Name.ToString());


            if (property != null)
            {


                object dataValue = Convert.ChangeType(attribute.Value, property.PropertyType);



                 property.SetValue(player, dataValue);

            }
        }

        return player;
    }


   public override void Write(Player value)
   {

        PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(Player).GetProperties();

        XElement playerElement = new XElement(XmlChildName);

        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            playerElement.Add(new XAttribute(property.Name, property.GetValue(value,   null).ToString()));
        }

        _doc.Root.Add(playerElement);

        _doc.Save(Path);
    }
```

Comment: what's the reservation with xml serializer class?

Comment: I agree that the xml serializer might work very well for you. Personally though i'd be worried the Player class at one point needs properties that you do not want to be serialized. Then you might consider offloading Save() and Load() to the Player class.

Comment: @Patrick: Yes, I wasn't clear, I meant that the implementation using reflection might get hairy, not the one using the xml serializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like this. I reversed the traversal to the attributes, not the properties. If there is a property with the name of the attribute, it is changed:

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(Player).GetProperties();

foreach (XAttribute attribute in playerElement.Attributes())
{
    PropertyInfo pi = properties.Where(x => x.Name == attribute.Name).FirstOrDefault();

    if (pi != null)
    {
        pi.SetValue(player, attribute.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome thanks for the guidance, I ended up with using this solution it seems to work well. I'll update the code